# vite + vuejs 3 Get vue instance at mount()

Tags: vuejs3, vue-cli, vite

I am facing something strange.

When I get the vue instance with vue-cli. I get a proxy with $ store, $ router etc. But with 'vite' I get a proxy of proxy from which I can't find $ store etc.

```
 let app = createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .mount("#app");

console.log(app);
```

From vue-cli based app :
[image]

From vite based app :
[image]

Does anyone know how to get the instance up vite ? Did I miss something?

Thanks by advance. =]

Answer (score 0):

App.vue has been written with script setup. component instances created from such a component definition will have a closed public interface by default.

And createApp(App).mount() returns the instance created from App.vue
If you write App.vue without  you will find it has $store etc.

And with , you can use defineExpose() to explicitly expose individual APIs. example:

```
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

const store = useStore()
defineExpose({
  $store: store
})
```

If you did that in App.vue, you would now find that the logged object has a $store property